# exact equations: integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I go about finding the integrating factor for the equation:

$$3x + \frac{6}{y} + (\frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{3y}{x})\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

can I find it using the following method?

$\frac{N_x - M_y}{xM-yN}$ ? if yes, then I didnt manage to find the correct one, the solution says the integrating factor should by xy ?

any tips/advice solutions on how I can find the integrating factor to this problem? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general form for your differential equation is
$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$
Thus we identify:
$$M=3x+\dfrac{6}{y},\quad N=\dfrac{x^2}{y}+\dfrac{3y}{x}$$
We then compute the derivatives:
$$M_x=3,\quad M_y=-\dfrac{6}{y^2},\quad N_x=\dfrac{2x}{y}-\dfrac{3y}{x^2},\quad N_y=-\dfrac{x^2}{y^2}+\dfrac{3}{x}$$
The first thing to check, for exactness, is whether $M_y=N_x$. Clearly this isn't the case.

Next, we look at the following expression and check if it is a function of $x$ only:
$$\dfrac{M_y-N_x}{N}=\dfrac{-6x^2-2x^3y+3y^3}{x^2y^2}\cdot\dfrac{xy}{x^3+3y^2}\neq f(x)$$
Therefore the integrating factor is not a function only of $x$. We check similarly for $y$:
$$\dfrac{N_x-M_y}{M}=\dfrac{6x^2+2x^3y-3y^3}{x^2y^2}\cdot\dfrac{y}{3xy+6}\neq f(y)$$
Therefore the integrating factor is not a function only of $y$. We finally check for a function of both $x$ and $y$:
$$\dfrac{N_x-M_y}{xM-yN}=\dfrac{6x^2+2x^3y-3y^3}{x^2y^2}\cdot\dfrac{xy}{2x^3y+6x^2-3y^3}=\dfrac{1}{xy}=f(x,y)$$
Therefore, the integrating factor will be:
$$\mu(x,y)=\exp\left(\int \dfrac{dx}{x}\right)\exp\left(\int\dfrac{dy}{y}\right)=xy$$

Comment: wow thanks! I managed to get the first expression:

Comment: (6x^2 +2x^3y-3y^3)/(x^2*y^2), but why do you multiply it with the other expression?

Comment: @yeyyeat You mean, why do I have two fractions multiplied? The first one is the numerator, brought together as one fraction, and the second one is the inverse of the denominator.

Comment: oh ok I see the first one is N_x-M_y and the second one is xM-yN inverse right?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: oh ok but how does that simplify to 1/xy ?u have (2x^3*y)/(2x^3) no? since the 6, 3 term simplify out to 1 and one xy term from the denominator get simplified out? is that a mistake or something? maybe the inverse one should be 2y*x^3 ?

Comment: also I dont really understand the last line, could you please explain? (the  dx/x and dy/y part) :D

Comment: @yeyyeat Sorry, I'd missed a $y$, thanks :) For the last line, we take the integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$ as the exponential of the integral of the function we've just found, $\frac{1}{xy}$. And the integral of $1/x$ is $\ln{x}$, such that $\exp{\ln{x}}=x$. Same thing for $y$.

Comment: ok thanks a lot man!

Comment: just wondering one last thing, if I found a function of x right away with the first formula I would still have to integrate it right? with the exponent etc? :D

Comment: @yeyyeat Yes, you would have $\mu(x)=\exp(\int f(x)dx))$ with $f(x)$ the function you'd obtained.

Comment: ahh ok thank you! I was just making sure :D

Answer (score 0):

The first step in solving such a differential equation is checking if it is exact.

To do so, first write the differential equation in standard form, that is

$$Mdx + Ndy = 0$$

Then check if $N_x = M_y$

If this is not the case, you must check with of

$$\frac{M_y - N_x}{-M}$$
$$\frac{M_y - N_x}{N}$$

will give you a function of x or y alone.

The one you pick will be the integrating and I trust you know how to do the rest.

Comment: didnt get a function of x or y alone on any of the two formulas..?

Comment: Working it out, give me a few.

Comment: It's not working out for me, can you double check your initial differential equation?

Comment: its not the correct one, the first term should be 3x + 6/y, but thats the one I have been using and it didnt work out for me..

Comment: fixed the equation now.

Comment: do you have any idea how I can find the integrating factor ?

Comment: I got to here but it's not working out.

$$(3x+ \frac{6}{y}) + (\frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{3y}{x})\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
$$(\frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{3y}{x})\frac{dy}{dx} = -(3x+ \frac{6}{y})$$
$$(\frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{3y}{x})dy = -(3x+ \frac{6}{y})dx$$
$$(3x+ \frac{6}{y})dx + (x^2 + \frac{3y^2}{x})dy = 0$$

Thus $M =3x+ \frac{6}{y}$ and $N =x^2 + \frac{3y^2}{x}$

$M_y = -\frac{6}{y^2} \neq N_x = 2x -3\frac{y^2}{x^2}$

$\implies$ This is not exact.

$M_y - N_x = -\frac{6}{y^2} -2x + 3\frac{y^2}{x^2}$

$$\frac{M_y - N_x}{N} = \frac{-\frac{6}{y^2} -2x + 3\frac{y^2}{x^2}}{x^2+ 3\frac{y^2}{x}}$$